# Do an action from ViewModel right after ShowDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await, task

I have a `ViewModel` like this:

```
public class WelcomeWindowVm : ViewModel
{
    private ViewModel view;

    public WelcomeWindowVm(){
        this.View = new LoginVm() { 
            Completed += (o, e) => {
                this.View = new OtherVm(e.User){ 
                    Completed += (o, e) =>; // and so on
                } 
            }
        };
    }

    public ViewModel View {
        get {
            return this.view;
        }

        set {
            this.view = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.View));
        }
    }
}
```

`LoginVm` is another Viewmodel whose Completed event is triggered when a Command on it is completed (The event is only triggered when correct login credentials are used). `OtherVm` is another vm whose completed event is triggered for whatever reason.

I render the `View` using a `DataTemplate`. For example:

```
<Window.Resources>   
   <DataTemplate DataType="vm:LoginVm">
         Textboes and buttons here
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="vm:OtherVm">
        ...
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<ContentControl Content={Binding View} />
```

The DataContext of this window is set to `WelcomeWindowVm` class above, before `ShowDialog`.

This works well. When the Window is shown using ShowDialog, `LoginVm` is shown. Then `OtherVm` when whatever task of LoginVm is completed, and so on.

Now I thought of converting the Completion stuff to Async/await pattern. The LoginVm now looks like this:

```
public LoginVm{
    ...
    private TaskCompletionSource<User> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<User>();
    ...
    // This is the Relay command handler
    public async void Login()
    {
        // Code to check if credentials are correct
        this.taskCompletionSource.SetResult(this.user);
        // ...
    }

    public Task<User> Completion(){
        return this.taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }
}
```

Instead of this:

```
public LoginVm{
    public event EventHandler<CustomArgs> Completed;

    // This is the Relay command handler
    public async void Login()
    {
        // Code to check if credentials are correct
        OnCompleted(this.user);
        // ...
    }
}
```

So that I can use it like this:

```
public WelcomeWindowVm(){
    var loginVm = new LoginVm();
    this.View = new LoginVm();
    User user = await loginVm.Completion();

    var otherVm = new OtherVm(user);
    this.View = otherVm;
    Whatever wev = await otherVm.Completion();

    //And so on
}
```

But I can't use await in a Constructor and even if I use an async Method for that, how will I call it in another class after calling `ShowDialog` since `ShowDialog` blocks?

I think using an `async void` will work. But from what I have heard, it should be avoided unless I am using it in an event handler.

Maybe use an `async Task` method but not `await` it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
    public WelcomeWindowVm() {
        var loginVm = new LoginVm();
        this.View = loginVm;
        loginVm.Completion().ContinueWith(loginCompleted =>
        {
            var otherVm = new OtherVm(loginCompleted.Result);
            this.View = otherVm;
            otherVm.Completion().ContinueWith(whateverCompleted =>
            {

            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, how about putting it in an async Task method and not awaiting it?
I am not very familiar with custom tasks like this. So I am curious.

Comment: Well you should make sure exceptions cannot be thrown inside that method then. Ignoring awaiting is usually not recommended because exceptions thrown inside might be unobserved. If you take this into account then it's fine (though I personally prefer method above).

Comment: Is there any way to do what you have done without using ContinueWith? Using async await only?

Comment: I don't think you can do _exactly_ the same. You can put that stuff in async void method and call that from constructor, but that is bad (because of how exceptions would be handled) so better not do this. I personally don't see a problem with ContinueWith, but if you do, consider reading this: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html